# QGIS Colour points by date

Tags: qgis, symbology, date

I have a point layer representing bird sightings. Each sighting has a survey date associated with it. I am trying to figure out a way to have QGIS display these point in a way that each date has a distinct colour. E.g. all birds seen 18/03/22 might be green but all sightings on 21/03/22 would be blue. Short of creating a colour for every date of the year I cannot seem to find a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the `categorized` layer style?

Answer (score 2):

You have the categorized style in the symbology properties. You don't need to create one for every day, you can use the "Classify" bottom and QGIS do it for you, giving random colours to each date. If you don't want the random colours you can choose a color ramp.

For more info https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer

Comment: I had look at usining the categorised feature and that works well on the desktop version. I was hoping to go one step further so that when the data is initially gathered it could be categorised and coloured automateically. The data will be gathered on the Input app.